# A method for calculating this integral hermite polynomials

Tags: special-functions, improper-integrals, orthogonal-polynomials

I need proof this,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}H_n^{2}(x)x^2dx=2^nn!\sqrt{\pi}(n+\frac{1}{2})$

This is the idea: Multiply $(1-t^2)^{-1/2}e^{2x^2t/(1+t)}=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty}\sum}\frac{H_n^{2}(x)}{2^nn!}t^n,~~~|t|<1,$ by $x^2$, integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and evaluate the integral in the left-hand side, calling the result $\varphi(t).$ Then expand $\varphi(t)$ in powers of $t$ and equate coefficients of identical powers of $t$ in both sides of the equation  so obtained.
I have problems in evaluating the integral, and thus expand in powers of $t$. $(H_n(x)) Hermite-Polynomials$

Any ideas? would be helpful!

Comment: Are you sure there's an $x^{2}$ in the integrand? Otherwise, the integral looks like the normalization integral for Hermite polynomials (I see you're using the physicist versions, not the probabilist): $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}H_{n}^{2}(x)\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}\, n!\,2^{n}.$$

Comment: Where did you find this formula?

Comment: Check this [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280945/integral-of-hermite-polynomial-multiplied-by-exp-x2-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Method 1: recurrence relations and symmetries of the Hermite polynomials

Hint: I would use the relations

$$H_{n+1}(x)=xH_n(x)-H'_n(x), $$

$$H'_n(x)=nH_{n-1}(x) $$

and an induction argument, as follows. Let us suppose the steps $k=1,\dots,n-1$ are true; we want to show that

$$\int e^{-x^2}H_n^2(x)x^2dx=2^nn!\sqrt{\pi}(n+\frac{1}{2}). $$

Using the above relations the l.h.s is

$$\int e^{-x^2}H_n^2(x)x^2dx=\int e^{-x^2}x^2(xH_{n-1}(x)-H'_{n-1}(x))^2dx=
\int e^{-x^2}x^4H^2_{n-1}(x)dx \\
-2\int e^{-x^2}x^3H_{n-1}(x)H^{'}_{n-1}(x)dx
+\int e^{-x^2}x^2(H^{'}_{n-1}(x))^2dx=\\
\int e^{-x^2}x^4H^2_{n-1}(x)dx -2(n-1)\int e^{-x^2}x^3H_{n-1}(x)H_{n-2}(x)dx
+\\(n-1)^2\int e^{-x^2}x^2(H_{n-2}(x))^2dx. ~(*)
$$

Let us discuss $(*)$: the first 2 terms can be reduced using integration by parts on the products

$$e^{-x^2}x^4H^2_{n-1}(x)=-(-\frac{1}{2}(2x)e^{-x^2})x^3H_{n-1}(x),$$
$$e^{-x^2}x^3H_{n-1}(x)H_{n-2}(x)=-(-\frac{1}{2}(2x)e^{-x^2})x^2H_{n-1}(x)H_{n-2}(x), $$

while the last term can be evaluated by the induction hypothesis.
All we need is to remember that

$$\int e^{-x^2}x^{2q+1}H^2_{r}(x)dx=0,$$
$$\int e^{-x^2}x^{2q}H_{r}(x)H_{r-1}(x)dx=0,$$

for all $q\in\mathbb N$, $r\geq 1$ for symmetry. For the second equality we used 
$H_r$ odd/even $\Leftrightarrow$ $H_{r-1}$ even/odd, which follows directly from the definition of the Hermite polynomials.

- Method 2: generating function

Using the generating function suggested by the OP, one needs to integrate w.r.t $x$ on the whole real axis both sides of

$$x^2e^{-x^2}e^{-\frac{t}{1+t}x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\frac{H_n^2(x)}{2^nn!}t^n,$$

and expanding w.r.t. $t$. The integral on the l.h.s. is Gaussian and can be evaluated with standard techniques reducing  to the case

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-\alpha(t)x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha(t)^3}}, ~(1)$$

for $\alpha(t)>0$ and $|t|<1$.

- Generating function with $\alpha(t)=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$

In the case under exam, multiplying both sides of the generating function identity w.r.t the product $x^2 e^{-x^2}$ ($e^{-x^2}$ is the weight for the integral identities involving the Hermite polynomials) and integrating, we arrive at (the exchange between summation and integration is allowed by the properties of Hermite poly.)

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2} e^{-\frac{t}{1+t}x^2}dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\frac{H_n^2(x)}{2^nn!}t^n; $$

to arrive at the thesis we write (using (1))

$$g(t):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-\frac{1-t}{1+t}x^2}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^3}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{1+t}{(1-t)^2}$$

for $|t|<1$ and we expand w.r.t $t$ at $t=0$ the function $g(t)$, obtaining

$$g(t)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(1+3t+\frac{1}{2!}10t^2+O(t^3)\right)$$

(the higher terms are easily computed, as well). This gives the thesis. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks Avitus, but I need to prove to the indications given. That in order to show the greatest problems with the same method:  $\frac{1}{2^nn!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2(x)}{1+x^2}e^{-x^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^n\frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx,~~~n=0,1,2...$

Comment: I see: returning to your strategy, you should multiply both sides of your generating function equation by $x^2 e^{-x^2}$, am I right? The overall idea sounds promising: one needs to compute a Gaussian integral.

Comment: no, in this case you should multiply both sides of your generating function equation by $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. The problem (for my) is how to calculate the resulting integral and then expoandir in powers of $t$?

Comment: If you do not multiply also by $e^{-x^2}$ both sides of the generating function equation, how can you arrive at integrals like $\int x^2 e^{-x^2}H_n^2 dx$?

Comment: this is the problem man

Comment: Avitus, here is raised the problem with your idea. On page 95 exer 8.  http://www.latp.univ-mrs.fr/~chaabi/ARTICLES%20IMPORTANTS/LEBEDEV/Lebedev%20Special%20functions%20and%20their%20applications.pdf

Comment: ok, gonna have a look at it

Comment: I think I got it: when in the book (ex.6) it is said that one should "multiply eq. 4.9.6 by $f(x)$ and integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$", then the integration *has* the weight $e^{-x^2}$, as I suggested. Try to prove the first relation of ex. 6: in this case you have $f(x)=1$ and integrating (do not forget the $e^{-x^2}$!) you arrive at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\int e^{-\alpha(t)x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{|1-t|}:=g(t)$. Expand this latter function at $t=0$ obtaining $g(t)=\sqrt{\pi}(1+t+...)$. Collecting all coefficients you are done. The case $f(x)+x^2$ is similar, as in my answer.

Comment: fine, and as is the RHS ?

Comment: I update the answer with the case you need.  Feel free to flag and upvote the answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

This can be proven by using the linearization of Hermite polynomials.  I will work in the probabilists in which case the integral becomes
$$
I_n = 2^{n-\frac{3}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{He}_n^2(x)x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx.
$$
Applying the linearization formula
$$
\operatorname{He}^2_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2k!\operatorname{He}_{2n-2k}(x)
$$
leads to the integral
$$
I_n = 2^{n-\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2k!\int_{-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{He}_{2n-2k}(x)x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx.
$$
Using $x^2=\operatorname{He}_2(x)+\operatorname{He}_0(x)$ together with orthogonality implies that the sum only has two non-zero terms
$$
I_n=2^{n-\frac{3}{2}}\left\{{n\choose n-1}^2 2!\sqrt{2\pi} + n!\sqrt{2\pi}  \right\}
$$
which reduces to precisely what was to be shown
$$
I_n = 2^n n!\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\sqrt{\pi}
$$